# Dot Net Client and IIS hosted SignalR with Win auth

Tags: signalr, windows-authentication

Is there a way to configure the .NET client so that it will work with a IIS hosted SingalR that uses Windows authentication?

If I disable windows authentication it works, but this is not an option

setting connection.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials does not help.

The code

```
public EventProxy(IEventAggregator eventAggregator, string hubUrl)
{
    typeFinder = new TypeFinder<TProxyEvent>();
    subscriptionQueue = new List<EventSubscriptionQueueItem>();
    this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;

    var connection = new HubConnection(hubUrl);
    connection.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    proxy = connection.CreateHubProxy("EventAggregatorProxyHub");

    connection.Start().ContinueWith(o =>
        {
            SendQueuedSubscriptions();
            proxy.On<object>("onEvent", OnEvent);
        });
}
```

ContinueWith triggerst directly after Start and when the first subscription comes in I get a

> The Start method must be called before data can be sent.
>   If I put a watch on the DefaultCredentials I can see that Username, Domain and Password are all String.Empty. Its a standard Console program, Enviroment.Username returns my username

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, set connection.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials. More details about credentials here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultcredentials.aspx.

Comment: Thanks David, yes i tried that without luck, but now that I know that that is how you should do it I can figure out why it isn't working.

Comment: Got it to work, I must have FOBARed the IIS configuration when trying to get it to work. If I deleted the virtual folder and recreated it with default settings and only enabling Win auth it works. Thanks for your help David